# Google Drive File Stream kicks regular Google Drive out of Windows Quick Access

Tags: windows, google-drive, google-drive-file-stream

I run Google Drive File Stream (GDFS) and Google Backup and Sync (GBS) simultaneously on Windows 10. I'd like to have both in the Quick Access list at the left of the Windows Explorer window. But it always seems to revert to having GDFS and not GBS in the list.

To replicate:

1. Have GDFS and GBS (Google Backup and Sync) installed and running.
2. Right click on the Google Drive (GBS) folder anywhere in Windows explorer, and Pin to Quick access.
3. Note that Google Drive does appear in the Quick Access list.
4. (Optionally, unpin GDFS from Quick Access. This does not make a difference.)
5. Restart Windows.
6. Note that GDFS is (back) in Quick Access and Google Drive is not.

Has anyone gotten this to work? Is there a hack by which I can force the change?

Comment: I'm having this same issue and it is extremely frustrating. Please update this post if you figure out a solution.

Comment: What happens if you rename Google Drive while it's on Quick Access?

Comment: You mean, rename the Google Drive folder? I can't normally; it's locked by the GBS process.
If I kill GBS, rename the Google Drive folder, start GBS, “locate” the missing Google drive folder, then restart, it appears to work. I now have the GDFS folder and the “Google Drive foobar” folder in Quick Access.
Of course, that's an ugly hack, unsupported (https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/AclZI-4R4C8/KdPnGnT_AQAJ), and I'll have to reconfigure other things that are pointing to Google Drive.

Comment: Update. After doing the same thing to rename it back to “Google Drive”, the problem reoccurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution 1 : Freeze the Quick Access bar

Apparently you are trying for the peaceful coexistence of two competing Google
products, or trying to keep a product that Google considers as deprecated.
In all cases, as the Google products have no parameter for achieving this,
then some hacking is required.

I understand that you can arrive at the situation where both icons are in the
Quick Access bar, only that this does not last beyond the next reboot.
My idea then is to freeze this state of the Quick Access bar and stop
Google, or any other program, from modifying it, hopefully without causing
spurious warnings during boot.

**Analysis**

According to the Microsoft article
[Users can't access the desktop and other resources through Quick Access in Windows 10](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/supportingwindows/2015/12/21/users-cant-access-the-desktop-and-other-resources-through-quick-access-in-windows-10/),
the Quick Access bar lives inside:

```
%appdata%\microsoft\windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms
```

Contrary to expectations, this is a simple file and not a folder.

The StackOverflow post
[Decrypt/Read/Modify “.automaticDestinations-ms” and/or “.customDestinations-ms”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429944/decrypt-read-modify-automaticdestinations-ms-and-or-customdestinations-ms)
further explains that this is a
[Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369%28VS.85%29.aspx)
file.
This ancient format is actually a file-system-within-a-file.
It is unknown why Microsoft went to all this just for the sake of a few icons.
The same post lists the open-source
[OpenMCDF project](https://github.com/ironfede/openmcdf)
as capable of reading and the basic editing of such files,
but we won't be doing that here.

**Procedure**

I suggest the following (untested) procedure:

- Set up the Quick Access bar to your liking
- Copy the file `f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms` as backup
  (on NTFS so as not to lose permissions)
- Right-click the file and choose *Properties*
- Try first in the General tab to set the file as Read-only and OK.
  If this is not enough:
- In the Security tab, click *Edit* and set Deny for Write.
  Do so for all the listed accounts, then click OK.
  You should not have any problem doing it, since you are the owner of the file.

You will need to undo it at any time that you would like to modify the
Quick Access bar.

## Solution 2: Rename Google Drive in the Quick Access bar

It seems like the Google Drive File Stream software searches for
Google Drive by name, so renaming it effectively disables this search.

Comment: I tested setting that file as "Read-only" and my quick access folders persisted on reboot. Thank you!

Comment: @Cory: Thanks, happy to know that this does indeed work.

Comment: @harrymc I was snowed in! I'm testing it now.

Comment: Read-only worked for me too. It's hacky, but meets the requirements I set. Thanks, and enjoy your bounty.

Comment: @harrymc If you want to write up the name change solution, I'd consider that a separate and pretty good answer, too.

Comment: Added into the answer as 2nd solution.